# Error for default parameter value of non-member template friend function

Tags: c++, templates, default-parameters, friend-function, non-member-functions

Why does the following code compile with GCC but not with Clang? Who is right and why?

```
class TF
{
        private:
                struct S
                {
                };

        template <typename T> friend void F(T x, S s, int v = 5);
};

template <typename T>
void F(T x, TF::S s, int v)
{
}
```

I get following error with clang++:

```
    error: friend declaration specifying a default argument must be a definition
        template <typename T> friend void F(T x, S s, int v = 5);
                                          ^
    error: friend declaration specifying a default argument must be the only declaration
    void F(T x, TF::S s, int v)
         ^
    note: previous declaration is here
        template <typename T> friend void F(T x, S s, int v = 5);
```

GCC version: g++ (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0

Clang version: clang version 6.0.0-1ubuntu2

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I resolve this?

As the error message says, you must define the function template to be able to have default arguments:

```
    template <typename T>
    friend void F(T x, S s, int v = 5) {
        // ...
    }
```

If you don't want that, you could remove the default argument and add an overload that acts as a proxy:

```
    template <typename T>
    friend void F(T x, S s, int v);

// ...

template <typename T>
void F(T x, TF::S s, int v) {
    // ...
}

template <typename T>
void F(T x, TF::S s) { F(x, s, 5); }
```

Another option is to make a forward declaration of the function:

```
template <typename T, typename S>
void F(T x, S s, int v = 5);

class TF {
private:
    struct S {};

    template <typename T, typename S>
    friend void F(T x, S s, int v);
};

template <typename T, typename S>
void F(T x, S s, int v) {
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<S, TF::S>);
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a gcc's [bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59480) which has been fixed; clang is correct. When specifying [default argument](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments) in friend declaration,

> If a friend declaration specifies a default, it must be a friend function definition, and no other declarations of this function are allowed in the translation unit.

That means you should define the function when declaring it as `friend` at the same time.

From the standard, [[dcl.fct.default]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.fct.default#5)

> If a friend declaration specifies a default argument expression, that declaration shall be a definition and shall be the only declaration of the function or function template in the translation unit.

BTW: [Gcc 11](https://wandbox.org/permlink/toM3vzWGAEyxu3Dd) doesn't compile either.

Comment: > "If a friend declaration specifies a default argument expression, that declaration shall be a definition and shall be the only declaration of the function or function template in the translation unit."...

The question is why is there such a rule?

Comment: @MeekaaSaangoo Sorry I don't know either, why the committee decided to make such a rule in the standard. You're asking which compiler is corrent, I answered it based on the standard. You might want to ask a new language-lawyer question about why the rule exists.